AJAX se ejecuta, pero no retorna nada ni genera ningún error
Buen día.
Tengo el siguiente método en AJAX
$("#idEmpleado").change(function () {

    var pStrValorSeleccionado = $(this).val();
    var StrUrl = "@Url.Action("GetNombre", "Home")";

    $.ajax({
        data: { IdEmpleado: pStrValorSeleccionado },
        url: StrUrl,
        method: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function (respuesta) {
            $('#idEmpleadoNombre').val(respuesta);
            if (respuesta == "Usuario no valido")
                $('#btnAccion').attr('disabled', 'true');
            else
                $('#btnAccion').removeAttr('disabled');
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.error("Error:", error);
        }
    }).fail(function (JqXHR, StrStatus, StrError) {
            alert("Request: " + JqXHR.responseText + "\n" + "Status: " + StrStatus + "\n" + "Error: " + StrError);
    });

})

Por otra parte, tengo el siguiente controlador:
using Equipos.AccessLayer;
using Equipos.Models;
using Equipos.ViewModel;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Equipos.Controllers {

    //Authorize es para la autenticacion de usuaroio, los usuarios Tipo Amin tienen acceso a todo, los tipo user no
    [Authorize]
    public class HomeController : Controller {

        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger) => _logger = logger;

        //el viewModel es para que cargue las asignaciones y los dropdown list (select) con opciones de la base de datos
        [Authorize(Roles = "ADMIN")]
        public IActionResult Index() {
            var viewModel = new AsignacionesViewModel();
            TbAsignacionesRepository asignacionesRep = new ();
            viewModel.Asignaciones = asignacionesRep.GetAsignaciones();
            return View(viewModel);

        }

        //SE accede a la misma vista de asignaciones pero cuando al controlador se manda un  parametro tipo view model de asignacions, depende de la entrada
        //agrega, modifica, o eliminamos algun registro
        [HttpPost]
        [Authorize(Roles = "ADMIN")]
        public IActionResult Index(AsignacionesViewModel asignacionVM) {
            var viewModel = new AsignacionesViewModel();
            TbAsignacionesRepository asignacionesRep = new TbAsignacionesRepository();

            switch (asignacionVM.Operacion) {
                case "Add":
                    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
                        //que el equipo no este asignado
                        //como se eso
                        //si existe un registro con el equipo
                        // QUE
                        //la fecha de devolucion es nula || la fecha de devolucion es anterior a la fecha actual 
                        //OO la fecha de desuso del equipo es nula || la fecha del equipo de desuso es despues de la fecha de hoy
                        //El empleado existe
                        //El empleado esta activo
                        //
                        Console.WriteLine("Si llega");
                        asignacionesRep.InsertAsignacion(asignacionVM.Asignacion);
                        ModelState.Clear();
                    }
                    break;
                case "Edit":
                    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
                        asignacionesRep.UpdateAsignacion(asignacionVM.Asignacion);
                        ModelState.Clear();
                    }
                    break;
                case "Return":
                    asignacionesRep.returnAsignacion(asignacionVM.Asignacion);
                    ModelState.Clear();
                    break;
                case "Delete":
                    asignacionesRep.DeleteEquipo(asignacionVM.Asignacion);
                    break;

            }

            viewModel.Asignaciones = asignacionesRep.GetAsignaciones();
            return View(viewModel);

        }

        //Es lo mismo que el index que va hacia la pantalla de asignaiciones pero en la lista de equipos
        [Authorize(Roles = "ADMIN")]
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult ListaEquipos(EquiposViewModel equipoVM) {
            var viewModel = new EquiposViewModel();
            TbEquiposRepository equiposRep = new TbEquiposRepository();
            viewModel.Categorias = TbCategoriasRepository.GetCategorias();
            viewModel.Marcas = TbMarcasRepository.GetMarcas();


            switch (equipoVM.Operacion) {
                case "Add":
                    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
                        equiposRep.InsertEquipo(equipoVM.Equipo);
                        ModelState.Clear();
                    }
                    break;
                case "Edit":
                    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
                        if (equipoVM.Equipo.ImagenBytes == null) {
                            viewModel.Equipos = equiposRep.GetEquipos();
                            var eq = viewModel.Equipos.Find(m => m.IdEquipo == equipoVM.Equipo.IdEquipo);
                            equipoVM.Equipo.ImagenBytes = eq.ImagenBytes;
                        }
                        equiposRep.UpdateEquipo(equipoVM.Equipo);
                        ModelState.Clear();
                    }
                    break;
                /*case "Obsoleto": 
                    equiposRep.ObsoletoEquipo(equipoVM.Equipo);
                    break;*/
                case "Delete":
                    equiposRep.DeleteEquipo(equipoVM.Equipo);
                    ModelState.Clear();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            viewModel.Equipos = equiposRep.GetEquipos();
            return View(viewModel);
        }


        [Authorize(Roles = "ADMIN")]
        public IActionResult ListaEquipos() {
            var viewModel = new EquiposViewModel();
            TbEquiposRepository equiposRep = new TbEquiposRepository();
            viewModel.Equipos = equiposRep.GetEquipos();
            viewModel.Categorias = TbCategoriasRepository.GetCategorias();
            viewModel.Marcas = TbMarcasRepository.GetMarcas();
            Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToBase64String(viewModel.Equipos[4].ImagenBytes));
            return View(viewModel);
        }

        [Authorize(Roles = "ADMIN, USER")]
        public IActionResult AsignacionesLectura() {
            return View();
        }

        [Authorize(Roles = "ADMIN")]
        [HttpPost("{usuarioVM}", Name = "Usuarios")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Usuarios(UsuariosViewModel usuarioVM) {

            Console.WriteLine("si llega");
            var viewModel = new UsuariosViewModel();
            var usuariosRep = new TbUsuariosRepository();

            switch (usuarioVM.Operacion) {
                case "Add":
                    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
                        var empleados = await new TbEmpleadosRepository().FnGetEmpleadosAsync();
                        var empleadoValido = empleados.Find(e => e.IdEmpleado == usuarioVM.Usuario!.IdEmpleado && e.Activo == true);
                        //var usuarioExistente = viewModel.Usuarios.Find(u => u.IdEmpleado == usuarioVM.Usuario.IdEmpleado || u.Correo == usuarioVM.Usuario.Correo); && usuarioExistente == null
                        if (empleadoValido != null) {
                            usuarioVM.Usuario!.Nombre = empleadoValido.Nombres + " " + empleadoValido.ApPaterno + " " + empleadoValido.ApMaterno;
                            usuariosRep.InsertUsuario(usuarioVM.Usuario);
                            ModelState.Clear();
                        }
                        else
                            Console.WriteLine("Usuario no valido");
                    }
                    break;
                case "Edit":
                    usuariosRep.UpdateUsuario(usuarioVM.Usuario!);
                    ModelState.Clear();
                    break;
                case "Delete":
                    usuariosRep.DeleteUsuario(usuarioVM.Usuario!);
                    ModelState.Clear();
                    break;
                default: break;
            }

            viewModel.Usuarios = usuariosRep.GetUsuarios();
            return View(viewModel);

        }

        [Authorize(Roles = "ADMIN")]
        public IActionResult Usuarios() {
            var viewModel = new UsuariosViewModel();
            var usuariosRep = new TbUsuariosRepository();
            viewModel.Usuarios = usuariosRep.GetUsuarios();
            return View(viewModel);
        }

        public IActionResult CambioContrasena(IFormCollection formulario) {
            TbUsuarios usuario = new TbUsuarios();
            TbUsuariosRepository us = new TbUsuariosRepository();
            usuario.IdEmpleado = Convert.ToInt32(formulario["idEmpleado"]);
            usuario.Contrasena = formulario["contrasena"];
            us.EditPasswordUsuario(usuario);
            Console.WriteLine("cambio y fuera");

            if (User.IsInRole("ADMIN"))
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            else
                return RedirectToAction("AsignacionesLectura", "Home");
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public JsonResult GetTime() {
            DateTime dateTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
            string response = dateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
            return Json(response);
        }

        [HttpPost("{idEmpleado}", Name = "GetNombre")]
        public async Task<JsonResult> GetNombreAsync([FromBody]string idEmpleado) {

            var empleados = await new TbEmpleadosRepository().FnGetEmpleadosAsync();
            var empleadoValido = empleados.Find(e => e.IdEmpleado.ToString() == idEmpleado && e.Activo == true);

            if (empleadoValido != null) return Json(empleadoValido.Nombres + " " + empleadoValido.ApPaterno + " " + empleadoValido.ApMaterno);
            else return Json("Usuario no valido");

        }

        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult GetEquipo(string IdEquipo) {
            var equips = new TbEquiposRepository().GetEquipos();
            var asigs = new TbAsignacionesRepository().GetAsignaciones();
            var cats = TbCategoriasRepository.GetCategorias();
            var equipoValido = equips.Find(e => e.IdEquipo.ToString() == IdEquipo);
            if (equipoValido != null) {
                var asigValida = asigs.Find(e => e.IdEquipo.ToString() == IdEquipo);
                if (asigValida == null || ((asigValida.FechaDevolucion < DateTime.Now && asigValida.FechaDevolucion != null) && (equipoValido.FechaObsoleto == null || equipoValido.FechaObsoleto > DateTime.Now))) {
                    string respuesta = equipoValido.Categoria;
                    respuesta += equipoValido.ActivoFijo != null ? $", Activo fijo: {equipoValido.ActivoFijo}" : "";
                    var resps = new { equipo = respuesta, asig = false };

                    return Json(resps);

                }
                else {
                    return Json(new { equipo = "Equipo ya asignado o en desuso", asig = true });
                }
            }
            else
                return Json(new { equipo = "Equipo no valido", asig = true });


        }

        [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        public IActionResult Error() {
            return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
        }

    }

}


En el cuál, se puede ver que el antepenúltimo método es el método GetNombreAsync (Renombrado en la etiqueta HttpPost como GetNombre.
Depurando el Script en el navegador, veo que el método change se invoca cada vez que la caja de texto con ID: idEmpleado cambia su valor, lo cuál me lleva a la llamada en AJAX, donde veo que se ejecuta y no genera ningún error (No sale por ninguno de los controladores de error que tiene indicados), pero también veo que la variable respuesta llega vacía al método en success. Adicionalmente, si pongo un BreakPoint al inicio del método GetNombreAsync del controlador, veo que tampoco se invoca, simplemente no se manda a llamar.

¿Qué podría estar pasando?
NOTA 1: Anteriormente, el método GetNombreAsync se llamaba GetNombre nada más y no era asíncrona, la cambié pensando en que eso podría solucionar el problema pero no, continúa.
NOTA 2: He intentado cambiar el AJAX agregando el type: "POST", el dataType: json, contentType: "application/JSON" etc. y nada ha funcionado...
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
EDICIÓN 1: Atendiendo a la recomendación de Jakala, intenté hacer el llamado a los métodos del Controlador usando PostMan, y ésto fué lo que encontré.
Prueba 1: Al llamar al método GetNombre, Postman resuelve con código 200. Es decir, que sí encontró el recurso, pero no retornó nada.

Prueba 2: Al llamar al método GetNombressss (Que intencionalmente escribí mal para que no lo encuentre) Postman también resuelve con código 200. (¿No debería indicar que el recurso no fué encontrado?) Igualmente, no devuelve nada.

Prueba 3: Intenté forzar un error (Agregando un elemento más al path para que de plano no lo encuentre) y efectivamente, ahora sí me mostró un error 404: Not found.

Una disculpa, soy relativamente nuevo con ésto de MVC con Controladores, quizá algo estoy haciendo mal. Les comento que éste código funcionaba, hasta que agregué una vista parcial de un componente de búsqueda genérico (con su propio Controlador). Esta PartialView funciona sin problema y está incrustada dentro de la misma View cuyo Controller ahora no me está funcionando. Si necesitan más detalle de ésto, sin problema puedo ahondarlo.

Has probado con alguna herramienta externa (postman) para ver si al hacer la petición desde ahí te devuelve algún resultado? Más que nada por confirmar que el extremo al que llamas devuelve algo y poder descartar problemas.

Estoy tan abrumado por éste tema que ni lo había pensado. Buena idea Jakala... pruebo y te comento.

Buen día Jakala. una disculpa por la demora, he tenido algunas complicaciones en el trabajo y me ha resultado complicado responder. Actualicé el POST agregando las pruebas con Postman que me sugeriste. Muchas gracias por el apoyo.
